# How to fetch Certificate Issuer name by loading a pem file in python?

Tags: python, x509certificate

I am trying to fetch the `certificate issuer name` from a pem file. But I am getting an error.

> ValueError: Unable to load certificate. See https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq/#why-can-t-i-import-my-pem-file for more details.

Here are the commands which I used to create the keys.

```
openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey -noout -out PrivateKey.pem

openssl ec -in PrivateKey.pem -pubout -conv_form compressed -out PublicKey.pem
```

And when I executing the below command,

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in PublicKey.pem
```

getting the error:

> unable to load certificate
> 140351154677056:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

And here is the my python code to fetch issuer name,

***.py**

```
  with open('PublicKey.pem','r') as pub_key:
    pubkey = pub_key.read().encode()
    cert_info = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(pubkey, default_backend())
    print('cert_info',cert_info)
    print('cn',cn)
    cn = cert_info.issuer.get_attributes_for_oid(NameOID.COMMON_NAME)[0].value
    print('cn------',cn)
```

Am getting the error `Unable to load certificate`.

I also need to fetch the `serial number`.
How can i solve this?

Comment: `PublicKey.pem` is not a certificate, it's just a public key.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, Thank you for your response, As per my development document its saying the I need to fetch certificate issuer name( X509 Serial Number). Please help me to resolve this. If you need any more details to my question, let me know.